# Did The Producers of "Stargate: Universe" Ever Reveal What the Superstructure Was?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

I remember after *Stargate: Universe* was cancelled, that I read, somewhere on the web, either part of an interview or an article by one of the producers about what they were planning if there had been a third season.  (He said they weren't sure whether they'd set it soon after the ending of the second season, or later, or were going to do something else.)

He also wrote that, while he felt okay discussing that, he did not feel like he could reveal how the story about the superstructure the *Destiny* had found would turn out.  He said that was something the other two producers had worked out and he didn't want to reveal it and would leave it up to them to reveal it if they wanted to.

Was this ever revealed?  Did the other producers ever discuss or reveal anything about what was going to happen with that storyline?

---

**Addition**: I'm referring to the superstructure that is the message found in the background radiation throughout the universe, not anything from the planet builders or other easily seen physical structures.

Comment: AFAIK, they haven't continued that story in another medium.  No comics, or web series.

Comment: They said it wouldn't be continued, but one of the producers did talk about the possibility that at some point the other producers might reveal what they had planned in a discussion or interview or something.

Answer (score 5):

Some information can be found here [Author Marjorie Liu answers your questions](https://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/may-14-2011-author-marjorie-m-liu-answers-your-questions-stargate-sg-1-memories-i-field-your-stargate-universe-queries-and-more/)

> “3.) You discussed the planet builders in this post; why were they helping the Destiny crew (creating Eden, sending Caine etc back)? What did they hope to gain from it? And if they weren’t helping us, what were they doing?”
>
> Answer: I believe that they felt some responsibility for the death of the Destiny crew and sought to make amends by restoring them and returning them to the ship.  Given what we know about the planet builders, it’s highly probable that this was also part of an experiment to learn more about humans and Destiny itself.
>
> Lou Zucaro writes: “Joe, when you say that your idea for the planet
>   builders included that they didn’t evolve from a physical form like
>   ours, can you elaborate on that? Were they energy beings? Mechanical?
>   Or just a lifeform vastly different than humans / humanoids?”
>
> Answer: We never got that far, but I envisioned them as lifeforms
>   vastly different than humans.

Comment: While that talks about the planet builders, it doesn't really address the issue of the vastly larger underlying structure of the Universe that the _Destiny_ was investigating.

Comment: @TangoOversway You should edit your question to make it clear the superstructure is the message hidden in the background radiation of the universe, and not a 'large' or 'super' structure like the planet the planet builders made.

Comment: That's an excellent point, @Keen.